# Why the redundancy?

Tags: parshat-nasso

In Bamidbar 5:4, the Pasuk reads: וַיַּעֲשׂוּ כֵן בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וַיְשַׁלְּחוּ אוֹתָם אֶל מִחוּץ לַמַּחֲנֶה כַּאֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר יְהוָֹה אֶל משֶׁה כֵּן עָשׂוּ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל

Why this redundancy? It says "they did it" in the beginning and "they did it" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

[Meshech Chochma commentary](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) implies that this was stated as a warning not to allow metzora people to be in the camp. But, these people exited the camp on their own joyously, becuae this way they could attone for their sins. Thus, the peole would noyt have been fulfilling the commandment as Moses and Aaron told them. Therefore, it says that the people, nonetheless, went outside the camp to warn these people about what Moses and Aaron told them.